# Ticketstatus on DynamicsCRM updates on TFS Ticketstatus change

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, dynamics-crm, status

I have a question about implementation of TeamFoundationServer in DynamicsCRM.
Our Company uses TFS as a Tool for TicketsManagment. Tickets on TFS can be created from our OnPremise Microsoft DynamicsCRM.
On Dynamics, a custom Plugin can be triggered by a RibbonButton to create on our TFS a ticket containing all the Infos from that specific "new_Ticket" Record.

So far so good. Everything works.

Now I´d like to go in the reverse Direction: when a Ticket´s Status gets modified on TFS, modifications should be mirrored and applied to the new_Ticket Record on CRM. I am interested to do so only for the status.

I quite don't know how to make things working though. I also dont know if that is possible.

I was thinking of having a process on my CRM that runs every once in a while, like an hour, and to check all tickets and rewrite what found different, but it´s not really ideal since we have 10k+ tickets and I would end up query all of them every hour. A solution to that would be to query only tickets modified in the last hour, if I run the process every hour. But that´s still not ideal.

I am looking for an "onChange" event listener of some sort that I can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for an "onChange" event listener of some sort that I can use

On On-Prem TFS, you can use [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops-2022) to monitor on the work item status change. Once the status is updated, it will send a JSON representation of an event to a service.

[image]

You need create a service to receive, parse the json content, and then create a new_Ticket Record on your local Dynamics CRM.

Comment: thanks @wade zhou - MSFT. It seems easy and straightforward. thanks.